# Collapse Rows in Hive and Keep Non-Null Values

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table in Hive where the athr_name and post_date fields are 90% null (represented by '?' in Hive).  I would like to query the table and GROUP BY athr_name, post_date, page_nm and visit_date to get counts of visits and visitors.  However, I would also like to combine and replace the null values with the values where athr_name and post_date is not null (page_nm contains unique values, so there can only be the correct athr_name or a null).

In other words, I have this:

```
   athr_name post_date         page_nm visit_date visit visitors
1      Steve  9/1/2019 /page1/content/   20191014    45       11
2      Steve  9/1/2019 /page1/content/   20191015    62       38
3      Steve  9/1/2019 /page1/content/   20191016    28       49
4      Steve  9/1/2019 /page1/content/   20191207    54       70
5      Steve  9/1/2019 /page1/content/   20191208    39       26
6          ?         ? /page1/content/   20191014    28       24
7          ?         ? /page1/content/   20191015    17       63
8          ?         ? /page1/content/   20191016    48       40
9          ?         ? /page1/content/   20191017    47       14
10         ?         ? /page1/content/   20191018    33        1
```

and I want to collapse that data to this result:

```
  athr_name post_date         page_nm visit_date visit visitors
1     Steve  9/1/2019 /page1/content/   20191014    73       35
2     Steve  9/1/2019 /page1/content/   20191015    79      101
3     Steve  9/1/2019 /page1/content/   20191016    76       89
4     Steve  9/1/2019 /page1/content/   20191017    47       14
5     Steve  9/1/2019 /page1/content/   20191018    33        1
6     Steve  9/1/2019 /page1/content/   20191207    54       70
7     Steve  9/1/2019 /page1/content/   20191208    39       26
```

It could be addressed by a coalesce function if it were columns instead of rows.  Any assistance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to fill nulls values with [LAST_VALUE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics). Your query may look like:

```
SELECT athr_name, 
       post_date, 
       page_nm, visit_date, 
       sum(visit), 
       sum(visitors)
from (
    select nvl(athr_name, LAST_VALUE(athr_name, TRUE)
                                              OVER (ORDER BY page_nm, athr_name NULLS LAST ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) as athr_name,
           nvl(post_date, LAST_VALUE(post_date, TRUE)
                                              OVER (ORDER BY page_nm, post_date NULLS LAST ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) as post_date,
           page_nm,
           visit_date,
           visit,
           visitors
    from your_table) as tmp_view
GROUP BY athr_name, post_date, page_nm, visit_date;
```

**UPDATE:**

If it's possible that you don't have corresponding athr_name or post_date for some page_nm it's better to use this query to keep this information:

```
SELECT athr_name, post_date, page_nm, visit_date, sum(visit), sum(visitors)
from (
         select name_view.athr_name as athr_name,
                date_view.post_date as post_date,
                main.page_nm,
                main.visit_date,
                main.visit,
                main.visitors
         from your_table main
                  LEFT JOIN (select athr_name, page_nm, row_number() over (PARTITION BY page_nm) as rn
                             from your_table
                             where athr_name is not null) name_view
                            ON main.page_nm = name_view.page_nm AND name_view.rn = 1
                  LEFT JOIN (select post_date, page_nm, row_number() over (PARTITION BY page_nm) as rn
                             from your_table
                             where post_date is not null) date_view
                            ON main.page_nm = date_view.page_nm AND date_view.rn = 1) as tmp_view
GROUP BY athr_name, post_date, page_nm, visit_date;
```

Comment: Thanks @Lyashko, I am finding I have some underlying data issues, but I believe this solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select max(athr_name), max(post_date), page_nm, 
       visit_date, sum(visit), sum(visitors)
from t
group by page_nm, visit_date;
```

Comment: No, I believe that would work in SQL, but it doesn't seem to work in Hive.  I get the same result with and without the max() statements.

Comment: @P5C768 . . . If you can remove the `max()`s then your `group by` is not the same as in this answer.